# how to draw a customized element using HTML and css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw a element in HTML and CSS. This is the shape of the element.

[image: Custom Shape of Element]

Can anyone help in getting this shape in HTML CSS. Any help or directions will be appreciated.

I am using Bootstrap. The above image is the single element of the three column layout. The three column layout is shown in the below image.

[image: 3 Column Layout]

```
<div class="row" >
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <!--Custom Shape Here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <!--Custom Shape Here -->     
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <!--Custom Shape Here -->
        </div>
   
   </div>
```

Comment: Please post your code snippet, so that we can get to know what and how you are trying

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and, if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried.

Comment: @ prateek and @ FeelRightz : In css you need the design and implement the design...I have the design and I want to write the html css but not able to...so I shared the images...Images are more than sufficient to help you understand the problem...So I made the problem very clear...secondly attempt...my attempt was to create bootstrap division of columns..I donot know how to make the custom element ..do you just want me to make anything just to show attempt..

Comment: @Prateek If you think I have not made a sufficient search why dont you redirect me to the answer where this problem has solution...I have searched thoroughly even tried using clip path but there is no solution to the problem

Comment: @PushkalSingh, don't just "make anything just to show attempt". If you really want to try, try to your fullest because SO as a community only helps those who help themselves. Check my answer below with a code snippet to try something. And no problem will have an exact solution, you need to find a way to code through it.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. You should get motivation with this snippet.

Then edit your answer if you run into any problem.

```css
.card {
    width: fit-content;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.first {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.second {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 45% 100%);
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
        <div class="first">Education technology lorem ipsum lorem ipusm</div>
        <div class="second">B</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

You can try online here [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: if you see the element has a border radius...How will I get that Border radius ?